# Are Sordward and Shielbert foreshadowed?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

In the postgame of Pokémon Sword and Shield, the player's character encounters two surprise villains, Sordward and Shielbert, who are apparently two brothers who claim to be heirs to the throne of Galar.

It occurred to me that I don't recall any foreshadowing of these characters or their royal claim anywhere in the actual game up to the point they are encountered. This contrasts strongly with the other surprise secondary antagonist,

> Rose

who drops many hints that he is *up to something*. The exact nature of his plans isn't clear until you actually confront him in the lead-up to becoming Champion, but it's hard to miss the hints that his activities could prove detrimental to the region.

So, are Sordward and Shielbert foreshadowed anywhere in the main game (and I just missed those hints) or do they truly appear out of the blue?

Comment: Thank you for using a spoiler tag!

Answer (score 6):

You didn't miss any hint, because there weren't. At least, as far as I remember.

And it's a pity, since Sordward and Shielbert were way better villains and had a reasonably believable motivation for what they do.

The game plot focuses too much on Rose, and the usual "good guy becomes the bad guy" thing. I feel the story has been handled so badly falling back on the same old flaws. Everything is just so surface value for the entire game, there's no depth or understanding or motivation for half that happens.

So if you think that Sordward and Shielbert appear "out of the blue", it's true.

Comment: And the design of those 2 is soooo bad.

Comment: @Pinkerman Bad, and *awkward*. I felt the main story to Sword/Shield had a strong finish, but the start of the post-game story felt really out of of place

Comment: @Wondercricket the probably just had the idea of a secret villain and they thought to add them to the post-game without effort or time to develop it decently. Game Freak in a nutshell.